How to clean xrdp log
While cleaning up some space in Ubuntu 20.04 I removed (fortunately left in trash) xrdp.log which is 1.5G from log folder. After that RDP stopped working. I restored the log file back, restarted xrdp service and got RDP fixed.
But is there any way to have log file cleaned? Can I delete its content without removing file? And is there a way to limit xrdp.log size?
In xrdp.ini there's no Logging section I could check and update with proper size setting, and I'm not sure how to add it properly
